# Generate N distinct permutations of a very large list in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, permutation

So I have a vector of numbers, say 1:8000. I want generate exactly `n` distinct permutations of this vector. What is a way to do this without having to calculate all permutations (since 8000! is huge and can't fit in RAM).

```
function distinct_permutations(L, N){
  # Return N distinct permutations of L as a list of lists
  return(x)
}

x <- seq(1:8000)
```

Comment: I think for relatively small N the sample function could be tempting.  I will sample n + n_eps samples of only indexes and take unique of them and cut the proper number of indexes at the end. BTW Probability of duplications is very small for relatively small N.

Comment: Another idea is that the one of the perm implementations is a recursive solution so we could stop it when get nth solution.

Comment: Ah I have nice idea to move each element by one position to the left or right it will be very efficient for upto N solutions

Answer (score 3):

Using `RcppAlgos::permuteSample`, here demonstrated with n=3 samples of 10 out of 10.

```
set.seed(42)
RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v=10, m=10, n=3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    9    8    5    3    4    1   10    6    2     7
# [2,]    1    3    5    9    7    6    8   10    2     4
# [3,]    2    8    5    9    4    7    3   10    6     1
```

Answer (score 2):

I will implement my first idea from 3 proposed in comments and compared with the already provided by other User. My solution is more universal as any set of values could be provided (other ones have to be treated as indexes), I provide a list of vectors and my solution is faster for many scenarios.

Current solutions:

- `perm_n` my own solution powered by `sample` and `unique`
- `RcppAlgos::permuteSample`
- `arrangements::permutations`

EDIT: added additional method

```r
perm_n <- function(vec, n) {
  # sample 2 * N samples as a risk of duplicates for bigger samples
  unique(
    lapply(seq_len(n * 2), function(x) sample(vec, length(vec)))
  )[seq_len(n)]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v=10, m=10, n=10),
  perm_n(1:10, 10),
  arrangements::permutations(10, 10, nsample = 10)
)
#> Warning in microbenchmark::microbenchmark(RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v = 10, :
#> less accurate nanosecond times to avoid potential integer overflows
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                              expr     min       lq      mean
#>  RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v = 10, m = 10, n = 10) 230.174 249.7105 1605.4817
#>                                  perm_n(1:10, 10)  65.559  68.0190  182.8387
#>  arrangements::permutations(10, 10, nsample = 10)   3.649   4.1205  238.7746
#>    median       uq      max neval
#>  1038.961 2292.556 28600.70   100
#>    71.217   82.861 10617.61   100
#>     4.633    7.298 23295.99   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v=8000, m=8000, n=10),
  perm_n(1:8000, 10),
  arrangements::permutations(8000, 8000, nsample = 10),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                  expr      min         lq
#>  RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v = 8000, m = 8000, n = 10) 199.5939 199.858108
#>                                    perm_n(1:8000, 10)   4.3911   4.428697
#>  arrangements::permutations(8000, 8000, nsample = 10) 593.0577 594.338993
#>       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>  200.44507 200.282540 200.944936 201.960178    10
#>    4.49205   4.457807   4.555182   4.663914    10
#>  600.67245 598.277678 604.146808 619.717132    10

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v=8000, m=8000, n=300),
  perm_n(1:8000, 300),
  arrangements::permutations(8000, 8000, nsample = 300),
  times = 3
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                   expr        min         lq
#>  RcppAlgos::permuteSample(v = 8000, m = 8000, n = 300)  5939.2831  5965.0268
#>                                    perm_n(1:8000, 300)   136.7174   137.3693
#>  arrangements::permutations(8000, 8000, nsample = 300) 17875.7788 17877.2049
#>       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>   5984.365  5990.7704  6006.9057  6023.0410     3
#>    138.048   138.0212   138.7133   139.4053     3
#>  17891.089 17878.6310 17898.7438 17918.8566     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You can also do this with the `arrangements` package. E.g. `arrangements::permutations(10, 10, nsample = 10)`

Comment: Thanks, I added your solution to the answer and benchmarks.

Comment: Nice! It looks like for your second benchmark you need `nsample = 10` instead of `nsample = 3`. Unless that is intentional?

Comment: Good catch i will update it:)

Answer (score 1):

For large vectors @polkas is correct that `lapply` with `sample` will be more performant.

To add more robustness to the solution already provided:

```
library(RcppAlgos)

perm_n.safe <- function(v, n) {
  if (n/permuteCount(v) > 0.01) return(as.list(data.frame(t(permuteSample(v, n = n)))))
  k <- 0L
  out <- vector("list", n)
  m <- n
  
  while (k < m) {
    s <- unique(lapply(1:n, function(i) sample(v)))
    out[(k + 1L):(k + length(s))] <- s
    k <- k + length(s)
    n <- ceiling(1.1*n/k)
  }
  
  out
}
```

This avoids a blind doubling of `n` and is guaranteed to return `n` samples.

```
set.seed(148461194)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  perm_n = perm_n(1:8000, 300),
  perm_n.safe = perm_n.safe(1:8000, 300),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>       perm_n 229.9223 231.2907 233.5303 233.0133 235.8125 237.5975    10
#>  perm_n.safe 117.1336 118.6889 123.5767 119.3938 122.4304 147.8789    10

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  perm_n = perm_n(1:5, 100),
  perm_n.safe = perm_n.safe(1:5, 100)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>         expr   min     lq    mean median    uq    max neval
#>       perm_n 728.8 766.75 908.462 789.85 993.4 3327.8   100
#>  perm_n.safe 168.9 186.90 211.721 200.80 228.4  414.1   100

sum(lengths(perm_n(1:5, 100)) == 5)
#> [1] 92
sum(lengths(perm_n.safe(1:5, 100)) == 5)
#> [1] 100
```